# Download file using CURL from URL

Tags: php, curl, download, gzip

I'm trying to download a file using PHP and CURL. If I open the link in a browser I would get an xlsx file, but with PHP when I save the file it can't be opened.
I find out that if I use PHP to save the content of url the file is a `gzip` file and if I save it as a `zip` file I can open it and it's ok.
The problem is that I want the extracted file on the server to work with and I can't extract the zip file because zip archive says that it's not a correct zip file.
This is the code I'm using :

```
$fp = fopen ('file.zip', 'w+');

// Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
$ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20","http:members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);

//  write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//   get curl response
$ex = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($ex); 
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$file = "images";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$path = realpath($file);
$res = $zip->open("file.zip");

if ($res === TRUE) {
    $extract = $zip->extractTo($path);
    var_dump($extract);
    if ($extract){
    $zip->close();
    echo "WOOT! $file extracted to $path";
}else{
    echo $zip->getStatusString(); 
    echo 'not extracte';
}

} else {
    echo $zip->getStatusString(); 
    echo "Doh! I couldn't open $file";
}
```

So my question is this. How can I have the excel file from that URL in my host?

I have tried so many thing and neither is working.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I found that the file saves perfectly OK and opens fine without requiring unzipping etc - not using the above code though

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,["Accept-Encoding: Identity"]);` - read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
    $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';    #EDIT THIS TO SUIT
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

    session_write_close();

    $curl=curl_init();
    if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    }
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );

    if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
        foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
    }
    if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    }
    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
    );
    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );
    curl_close( $curl );

    return $res;
}




/* Make the curl request and save the file */
$url='http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0';

$saveto='c:/temp/downloaded_excel_file.xlsx'; #EDIT TO SUIT

$fp=fopen( $saveto, 'w' );
$options=array( CURLOPT_FILE => $fp );
$res=curl( $url, $options );
fclose( $fp );

if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){
    echo "OK";
}
```

This happily saves the `xlsx` file which can then be opened in Excel. The size of the file saved with this is `145Kb` rather than `141Kb` with the original code

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the gzip encoding (as CURLOPT_ENCODING), then you don't need to extract the file (and the downloaded file could be opened directly):

```
$url = 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents('test.xlsx', $result);
```